# How do you install and configure TuxGuardian in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, firewall, tuxguitar

Can anyone guide me on the process to install TuxGuardian in Ubuntu 12.04? Its a freeware application available at:

***http://tuxguardian.sourceforge.net***

Answer (score 2):

You might try Leopard Flower instead. TuxGuardian hasn't been updated since 2006.

http://leopardflower.sourceforge.net/